# Swift shows Expected declaration error while using firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm new in Swift and I'm making a pretty simple login page using Firebase. I have this code:

```
 guard fullNameTextField.text != "", emailTextField.text != "", passwordTextField.text != "", confirmPasswordTextField.text != ""
        else {
            return
    }

    }

if passwordTextField.text == confirmPasswordTextField.text {
//MARK: Firebase autenthication
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion:{
(user,error)in

if let error = error {
print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

and the Xcode says that there is Expected a declaration error. I would be thankful if anyone could help me with this because I think I have tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update to latest version

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
  // ...
  guard let user = authResult?.user else { return }
}
```

Have a look here [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid force unwrapping. Your code should look like this:

```
guard let name = fullNameTextField.text, name.count > 0 else { return } 
guard let email = emailTextField.text, email.count > 0 else { return }
guard let password = passwordTextField.text, password.count > 0 else { return }
guard let confirmPassword = confirmPasswordTextField.text, confirmPassword.count > 0 else { return }

if password == confirmPassword {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to create new user", error)
            return
        }

        print("Successfully created user:", result?.user.uid ?? "")

        })
}
```